# Как получить переменную, изместную в скрипте в импортированный модуль?

Tags: python

модуль Lib.py:

```
def res():
    b = a
    print(b)
```

ноутбук на python:

```
from Lib import res
a = 1
global a
res()
```

Результат:

> name 'a' is not defined

Как в импортированной функции `res()` получить переменную `a`, не подавая `a` как входной параметр в скобках-`res(a)`

Comment: Только нормальные программисты за такой код больно надают по рукам. Если функция зависит от какой-то переменной — она должна получать её как входной параметр, а не выпендриваться

Comment: @andreymal , не работает. на печать не выводит значение a.

Comment: Ой, я напутал. `import Lib; Lib.a = чтонибудь`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На английском `SO` есть [рецепт](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15959638/8324991):

```
import Lib
Lib.a = 1
Lib.res()
```

Я проверил, вроде работает.

Суть в том, что глобальные переменные в питоне глобальны только внутри одного модуля. Но их можно задать вот таким образом в нужном модуле.

Хотя, конечно, глобальные переменные всё-равно зло и лучше передавать нужные данные в функцию явным образом.

Answer (score 0):

Импортировать свой ноутбук в модуле. Или только необходимые переменные.

Comment: Циклические импорты это иногда больно

Comment: Вот импортировать «только необходимые переменные» не получится именно из-за циклического импорта)

Comment: @andreymal Я может ошибаюсь, но, если импорт не перезагружается, то он считывается единожды, так что зацикленности быть не должно и переменная импортируется. Или я в чем-то не прав?

Comment: Вы забываете о том, что при циклическом импорте один из модулей оказывается загружен не полностью, и в итоге «необходимая переменная» может оказаться ещё не создана

Comment: Впрочем, если выполнять импорт внутри функции (то есть уже после полной загрузки всего везде), то всё-таки импортируется. Но я бы за такое всё равно надавал бы по рукам в воспитательных целях)

Answer (score 0):

Ещё можно так. Только это хуже, чем использовать глобальные переменные

main.py

```
from lib import func

f = func()
next(f) # обязательно в начале
f.send(5) # первый аргумент
f.send(6) # второй

try:
    next(f)
except StopIteration as e:
    print(e.value)
```

lib.py

```
def func():
    a = yield # первый аргумент
    b = yield # второй
    yield # обязательно в конце

    print(a, b)

    return a + b
```